# On 10.04, should I upgrade from Python 2.6.5 to 2.6.6?

Tags: upgrade, python

The default Python version on Ubuntu 10.04 server edition is 2.6.5.  The latest version of the Python 2.6 series is 2.6.6.  Does Ubuntu support 2.6.6 or should I leave it at the default version.  If I can upgrade the version, what's the corresponding apt-get command to upgrade the Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if Ubuntu will support to Python 2.6.6 when you run:

```
apt-get update
```

and then:

```
apt-get upgrade
```

automatically youll see the new version of python to upgrade, meanwhile you can keep the version 2.6.5...

cheers!!